# Extract data between two divs using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

```
    <div id="content">
        <div class="sample1">sample text1</div>
        <div class="sample2">
           <span style="float:right">some text2</span>
           <b>some text2</b>
        </div>
        <div class="sample3"> sample text <a href="#">This page</a> 3</div>
        <p>paragraph 1</p>
        <p>paragraph 2</p> 
        <div class="sample4">sample text4</div>
   </div>
```

I want to extract data that is between these classes "sample2" and "sample4".
The out put will show lik this
sample text 3
paragraph 1
paragraph 2

How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//*[
    preceding-sibling::div[@class = 'sample2'] 
        and following-sibling::div[@class = 'sample4']
]/text()
```

Comment: It's working but I am facing a problem if there is an a tag in "sample3" class between sample text and 3 like "sample text <a href="#"></a> 3"
So above code is giving output like
sample text
nothing after a tag :(
sorry I was posted uncompleted question before

Comment: I have update my question please see it again. The code that you provide me that is showing text only that is before <a href="#"> this tag. Not shown the data that coming after <a tag

Comment: @Dark, Well, in updated sample provided XPath selects 4 text nodes: `sample text`, `3`, `paragraph 1` and `paragraph 2`. Check: http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm